# how to get item id when collectionView cell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I just want to pass the item id to the next view controller when the item of collectionView is selected.

here I store the data that I get from API

here's some code -->

```
var posts = [[String: Any]]()
func apicall() {
        let Url = String(format: "http:example.com")
        guard let serviceUrl = URL(string: Url) else { return }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]{
                        
                        self.posts = (json["data"] as? [[String : Any]])!
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                            self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

now I get the data and I want to pass the item id of that item which is selected only

```
 @IBAction func onClickNext(_ sender: Any) {
        let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! secondViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
       
    }
```

here the code of the didSelectItemAt index path

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! secondCollectionViewCell
}
```

Comment: What does *item id* mean? The code doesn't contain anything like `id`.

Comment: cell id means the id of cell that I get in response from API  --  example - {
    "__v" = 3;
    "_id" = 60356f;
    createdAt = "2021-04-06T06:40:53.128Z";
    icons = "";
    id = 60356f;
    name = abc;
    updatedAt = "2021-04-06T06:40:53.128Z";
}

Comment: this is the response from API and I use the name and icon in collectionView item but id doesn't use and I pass id to the next view contoller

Answer (score 1):

Always get the data from the **model**, the data source array, never from the **view**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item = self.posts[indexPath.item]
        let id = item["id"]
        // do things with id
}
```

Comment: now please tell me how to pass this id to the next view controller, i use this  -->   @IBAction func onClickNext(_ sender: Any) {
        let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CreateGrupNameViewController") as! CreateGrupNameViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
       controller.groupId = id
    }

Comment: it shows me the error unresolved identifier id

Comment: Drop the IBAction and instantiate the controller in `didSelect` or use a temporary property.

Comment: I can't drop it because the next button is necessory, pass data only when the user select the item click on the Next button

Comment: Then create a temporary property.

Answer (score 0):

Well at that moment if you have the selection enabled the collection view will be able to return to you the `IndexPath` for all selected cells in the collection view.
Please take a look to this property on the `UICollectionView`

```
var indexPathsForSelectedItems: [IndexPath]? { get }
```

[apple documentation for indexPathForSelectedItems](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618099-indexpathsforselecteditems)

then at your `@IBAction func` just do this

```
@IBAction func onClickNext(_ sender: Any) {
  // logic to grab the id from self.posts using the selected indexPaths ie.
  let selectedItems = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems ?? []
  let ids = selectedItems.compactMap { self.posts[$0.row] }

  let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
           "secondViewController") as! secondViewController
  controller.selectedIds = ids // all the selected ids
  
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

so something like that you should do, i have no idea how the data structure looks like inside your `self.posts` property but the above code gives you an idea. To simplify this try to run below code in a playground and see the result.

```
import UIKit

let posts: [String] = ["Carrot_Post", "Pencil_Post", "Dish_Post", "Data_Post",
                       "iOS_Post", "Kitties_Post", "VideoGamesPost", "Bitcoin_Post"]
let selected: [Int] = [1, 3, 0, 5]

let items: [String] = selected.compactMap({ posts[$0] })

print(items) // output: ["Pencil_Post", "Data_Post", "Carrot_Post", "Kitties_Post"]
```

Hope that helps with your problem.